# What is the cancellation fee for Qatar Economy Flexi ticket?

Tags: cancellations, qatar-airways

I am looking to book a ticket with refund for cancellation and trying to identify the most the one which gives most of the amount as refund if not all. I noticed that Qatar airways Economy Flexi is offering cancellation free of charge. What does it mean if I cancel the entire ticket couple of days before the departure without using any of the flights booked - first and subsequent flight? Do they refund the whole amount without even any fee/penalty?

[image]

Here is the fare rule for refund:

[image]

Here are the Restrictions:

> 1 - PSGR P1 ADT                                   RULES DISPLAY FARE
>   COMPONENT  1    ADT MAAHEL QR  HLR4R1FI  PU 1 N FCL: HLR4R1FI  TRF:
>   4 RULE: RY05 BK:  H PTC: ADT-ADULT              FTC: EU -ECONOMY
>   UNRESTRICTED TE.TKT ENDORSEMENT
>
> THE ORIGINAL AND THE REISSUED TICKET MUST BE ANNOTATED -   NON
>   END/CHNG PENALTIES - AND - AS PER RULE - IN THE   ENDORSEMENT BOX.

Here are the Surcharges:

```
> 1 - PSGR P1 ADT                                   RULES DISPLAY FARE
> COMPONENT  1    ADT MAAHEL QR  HLR4R1FI  PU 1 N FCL: HLR4R1FI  TRF:  
> 4 RULE: RY05 BK:  H PTC: ADT-ADULT              FTC: EU -ECONOMY
> UNRESTRICTED SU.SURCHARGES BETWEEN MAA AND HEL   NOTE - RULE QA42 IN
> IPRG100 ALSO APPLIES
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN BOM AND
> DOH   ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY 9W FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 180.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN FRA/GVA
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN LON/MUC
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN PAR/VIE
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN ZRH/MOW
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN BER AND
> HEL   ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN CPH/STO
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY SK FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN MIL/ROM
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 60.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN PAR AND
> HEL   ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY SK FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 60.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN BER/FRA
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY LH FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 230.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN MUC AND
> HEL   ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY LH FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 230.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN BOM AND
> DOH   ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY 9W FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 180.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN FRA/GVA
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN LON/MUC
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN PAR/VIE
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN ZRH/MOW
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN BER AND
> HEL   ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN CPH/STO
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY SK FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 30.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN MIL/ROM
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY AY FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 60.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN PAR AND
> HEL   ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY SK FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 60.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN BER/FRA
> AND   HEL ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY LH FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 230.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   INBOUND -   IF THE FARE COMPONENT INCLUDES TRAVEL BETWEEN MUC AND
> HEL   ON
>       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>         ANY LH FLIGHT
>       A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE
>       APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>       AND - A SURCHARGE OF USD 230.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE
>             ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGE MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
>           -------------------------------------------
> 
>   OUTBOUND -
>     A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE
>     FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.
> 
>   INBOUND -
>     A SURCHARGE OF INR 1250 WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE
>     FARE FOR TRAVEL ON FRI/SAT/SUN.
>          NOTE -
>           ALL SURCHARGES MENTIONED ACCRUE TO QR ONLY.   *** GENERAL RULE FOLLOWS ***
> 
>   A SURCHARGE OF USD 10.00 PER DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO   THE
> APPLICABLE FARE FOR TRAVEL FROM 10APR 17 THROUGH   24APR 17.
```

Here are the Penalties:

> 1 - PSGR P1 ADT                                   RULES DISPLAY FARE
>   COMPONENT  1    ADT MAAHEL QR  HLR4R1FI  PU 1 N FCL: HLR4R1FI  TRF:
>   4 RULE: RY05 BK:  H PTC: ADT-ADULT              FTC: EU -ECONOMY
>   UNRESTRICTED PE.PENALTIES FOR HLR4R1FI TYPE FARES
>
> CANCELLATIONS
>
> ```
> ANY TIME
>   CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED.
>
> CHARGE USD 55.00 FOR NO-SHOW.
> ```
>
> CHANGES
>
> ```
> ANY TIME
>   CHANGES PERMITTED.
> CHARGE USD 30.00 FOR NO-SHOW.   *** GENERAL RULE FOLLOWS ***
>
>
>      NOTE -
>       NO-SHOW
>       A PASSENGER FAILS TO CHANGE/CANCEL HIS/HER
>       RESERVATION 3 HOURS PRIOR TO DEPARTURE ANY RE-
>       BOOKING MADE WITHIN 3 HOURS PRIOR TO
>       DEPARTURE OR AFTER DEPARTURE OF FLIGHT AS SHOWN
>       IN THE E-TICKET WILL BE CONSIDERED AS A NO-SHOW.
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       FOR A SCENARIO WHERE IN THE ORIGINAL RESERVATION
>       IS CANCELLED PRIOR TO NO-SHOW CONDITION BUT THE
>       NEW RESERVATION ARE MADE AFTER DEPARTURE OF THE
>       FLIGHT AS MENTIONED IN E- TICKET COUPON
>       RESERVATION AND TICKETING STAFF MAY PERFORM A
>       MANUAL TRANSACTION WITHOUT ATC ENTRIES TO AVOID
>       THE COLLECTION OF NO-SHOW FEE
>       -------------------------------------------------
>       IN CASE OF NO-SHOW CHARGE  REBOOK OR REFUND FEE
>       IN ADDITION TO NO-SHOW FEE
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       CHANGES -
>       FEES APPLICATION -
>       THE CHANGE FEE APPLIES PER TRANSACTION
>       THE CHANGE FEE APPLIES PER FARE COMPONENT.
>       WHEN MORE THAN ONE FARE COMPONENT IS CHANGED
>       THE HIGHEST PENALTY OF ANY OF THE CHANGED FARE
>       COMPONENTS WILL APPLY.
>       -------------------------------------------------
>       REPRICING SCENARIO-
>       1.BEFORE DEPARTURE
>        BEFORE UTILIZATION OF THE FIRST COUPON OF THE TKT
>        WHEN VOLUNTARY CHANGE OCCURS IRRESPECTIVE OF THE
>        OUTBOUND OR INBOUND FLIGHT OF THE JOURNEY THE
>        FARE WILL BE RECALCULATED APPLY NEW FARE/RULES
>        ADHERING TO THE AP CONDITION IN EFFECT ON THE
>        DATE OF THE RE-ISSUE.
>       2.AFTER DEPARTURE
>         AFTER UTILIZATION OF THE FIRST COUPON OF THE TKT
>         NEW FARE WILL BE RECALCULATED USING FARES IN
>         EFFECT ON THE DATE HISTORICAL FARES WHEN THE
>         ORIGINAL TICKET WAS ISSUED.
>       3.CHANGE PENALTY BEFORE/AFTER DEPARTURE WILL BE
>         CHARGED PLUS NO-SHOW CHARGES AND THE TICKET
>         NEEDS TO BE REISSUED WITH APPLICABLE FARE
>         DIFFERENCE IF ANY.
>       4.IN CASE OF REISSUED CHANGE/NO-SHOW FEES MUST
>         COMPLY WITH ALL PROVISIONS OF THE ORIGINALLY
>         TICKET FARE.
>       NOTE-
>        CHANGE/NO-SHOW FEES MUST BE CODED AS XP IN THE
>        TAX FIELD
>       -------------------------------------------------
>       1FOC CHANGE PERMITTED TO INBOUND ONLY FOR
>       BOOKINGS MADE WITH TRAVEL BEYOND SYSTEM
>       RANGE
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       NAME CHANGE NOT PERMITTED.
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       CHARGE APPLIES FOR ADULT  CHILD AND INFANT
>       OCCUPYING A SEAT. CHARGE INCLUDING NO-SHOW CHARGE
>       WILL NOT APPLY FOR INFANT NOT OCCUPYING A SEAT.
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       UPGRADE -
>       ANY TIME WITHIN THE TICKET VALIDITY FARES CAN BE
>       UPGRADED TO ANY FARE IN A HIGHER CABIN AND THEN
>       THE FARE WILL BE RECALCULATED FROM THE POINT OF
>       ORIGIN PROVIDED THE CONDITIONS OF THE HIGHER
>       CABIN HAVE BEEN MET. RE-ISSUE AND CHANGE FEE WILL
>       NOT BE APPLICABLE HOWEVER ADDITIONAL TAX-IF ANY
>       HAVE TO BE COLLECTED. IF THE RE-ISSUED TICKET IS
>       SUBSEQUENTLY CANCELLED THE ORIGINAL OR PENALTY OF
>       THE MOST RESTRICTED FARE WILL APPLY.
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       RE-ROUTING -
>       WHEN A VOLUNTARY CHANGE IS REQUESTED BY THE
>       PASSENGER  CHANGES ARE PERMITTED ON THE SAME OR
>       HIGHER BOOKING CLASS ONLY. IN CASE THERE IS A
>       CHANGE OF FARE BREAK POINT AND THE NEW FARE
>       RESULTS IN A LOWER FARE / TAX THE RESIDUAL VALUE
>       AFTER DEDUCTION OF PENALTIES AS APPLICABLE WILL
>       BE RETURNED TO THE PASSENGER IN THE FORM OF AN
>       EMD  FOR FURTHER TRANSPORTATION AND OR REFUND TO
>       THE ORIGINAL FORM OF PAYMENT.
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       WAIVERS -
>       WAIVED FOR DEATH OF PASSENGER OR FAMILY MEMBER.
>       ALL WAIVERS HAS TO BE PROCESSED THROUGH QR
>       OFFICES ONLY AND SUPPORTING DOCUMENT HAS TO BE
>       PRESENTED.
>       FULL REFUND PERMITTED BEFORE DEPARTURE IN CASE OF
>       REJECTION OF VISA. WAIVERS HAS TO BE PROCESSED
>       THROUGH QR OFFICES ONLY AND EMBASSY STATEMENT HAS
>       TO BE PRESENTED AS SUPPORTING DOCUMENT
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       CANCELLATION -
>       REFUND ON PARTIALLY USED TICKET -
>       APPLICABLE PENALTIES PLUS APPLICABLE OW FARE IN
>       SAME RBD. IF ONE WAY FARE IS NOT AVAILABLE OR
>       PUBLISHED ON THE INVENTORY MENTIONED ON THE
>       TICKET THEN DEDUCT NEXT AVAILABLE OW IN HIGHER
>       RBD FOR WHICH THE JOURNEY HAS BEEN PERFORMED
>       1.ANY NON-REFUNDABLE AMOUNT FROM A PREVIOUS
>          TICKET REMAINS NON-REFUNDABLE FOLLOWING A
>          CHANGE.
>       2.WHEN FARE COMBINED WITH A NON-REFUNDABLE FARE
>         THE CANCELLATION FEE WILL APPLY FROM THE AMOUNT
>         OF THE NON-REFUNDABLE FARE WITHOUT DEDUCT
>         ADDITIONAL CANCELLATION FEE.
>       -------------------------------------------------
>       FOR REFUNDABLE FARES REFUND REQUEST POSSIBLE
>       WITHIN 364 DAYS OF ORIGINAL TICKET ISSUE.
>       HOWEVER IT SHOULD DISTINGUISH BETWEEN PARTIALLY
>       AND FULLY UNUTILIZED E-TICKETS
>       PARTIALLY UTILIZED-364 DAYS FROM THE DATE OF 1ST
>       UPLIFTED COUPON
>       FULLY UNUTILIZED-364 DAYS FROM ORIGINAL E-TICKET
>       ISSUE
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       FOR NON-REFUNDABLE FARES YQ/YR AND SURCHARGES ARE
>       NON-REFUNDABLE
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       NON REFUNDABLE FARES YQ/YR PORTION ON REISSUED
>       TICKETS -
>       IF NON-REFUNDABLE FARE IS RE-ISSUED TO A
>       REFUNDABLE FARE YQ / YR WILL BE PROCESSED AS PER
>       THE NEW FARE CONDITION AND ONLY THE BASE FARE OF
>       THE ORIGINAL NON-REFUNDABLE TICKET REMAINS AS NON-
>       REFUNDABLE.
>       ------------------------------------------------
>       PARTIAL REFUND CALCULATION YQ/YR FOR REFUNDABLE
>       FARE WITH FEE -
>       IF APPLICABLE OW FARE PLUS CANCELLATION FEES
>       EXCEED THE ACTUAL COLLECTED BASE FARE FOR THE
>       JOURNEY  THE BASE FARE PAID REMAINS NON-
>       REFUNDABLE. ALL UNUTILIZED COUPONS FLOWN BASED
>       TAXES  INCLUDING YQ/YR WILL BE REFUNDABLE FOR
>       SUCH SCENARIOS.
>       TICKETS WHICH ARE USED BEYOND POINT OF TURNAROUND-
>       NO REFUND PERMITTED
>       OUT OF SEQUENCE  NO REFUND PERMITTED
>       --------------------------------------------------
>       WHEN A TICKET IS ISSUED WITH COMBINATION OF FARES
>       WITH DIFFERENT PENALTY RULES THE MOST RESTRICTIVE
>       CANCELLATION RULES WILL APPLY FOR THE ENTIRE
>       TICKET.IF A TICKET HAS BEEN RE-ISSUED MULTIPLE
>       TIMES AND FINALLY SUBMITTED FOR CANCELLATION/
>       REFUND THE HIGHEST CANCELLATION FEE/NON-REFUNDABLE
>       AMOUNT AMONG ALL THE REISSUED FARE WILL APPLY.
>       --------------------------------------------------
> ```

Where do I find exact cancellation fee for this type of ticket? I am quite sure there is a fee which is lying somewhere! Thank you.

Comment: It looks like there is no cancellation fee providing you cancel more than 3 hours before departure, otherwise you'd be charged the no-show fee

Comment: @Berwyn care to add that as an answer?

Comment: Qatar Airways customer service responded back that there is a full refund if I cancel it 3 hours before departure. More specific answer will be provided by contacting local QR office.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qatar Airways Flexi fares can be changed, canceled, and are fully refundable in all three classes (First, Business, and Economy, if done no less than 3 hours prior to the scheduled flight departure. After that, it is considered a no-show and a fee imposed.

> [**Qatar Airways**](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/fare-families.page)
>
> **Introducing our new fare families structure**
>
> Enjoy greater choice with our updated fare families. The new structure offers consistent and easy to understand travel options across cabins allowing you greater flexibility to choose fares that match your preferences and travel budgets.
>
> The new structure includes:
>
> **Promo Fare**
>   A Promo Fare is Qatar Airways’ lowest fare and is available only for a limited time. However, it comes with more restrictions than our other fare families.
>   **Saver Fare**
>   A Saver Fare is Qatar Airways’ base level entry fare and is available for sale and travel year round, subject to availability. These fares are changeable and refundable for a fee.
>   **Value Fare**
>   Value Fares allow cancellations and changes at a reduced fee along with a longer ticket time limit window as compared to our Saver fares.
>   **Flexi Fare**
>   Flexi Fares allow changes and cancellations at no cost (except in case of no show) and provide the longest ticket time limit.
>
> The tables below display a summary of the fare family conditions across First, Business and Economy Class. This summary is for reference only. Fare conditions may vary on some destinations. Please refer to the detailed fare rules which are displayed when you search for flights during the booking process.
>   [image]